# How to exit from multiple bash scripts

Tags: bash

I'm having a bash script that is calling multiple bash scripts.

e.g.:

**script1.sh**

```
source script_data.sh
bash script2.sh
variables
code ...
```

**script2.sh**

```
source script_new.sh
...
bash script3.sh
varialbles ...
code ...
```

**script_data.sh**

```
someVariable=1
functions() ...
...
```

**script3.sh**

```
code ...
variables ...
exit 0
```

The problem is that when I what to exit from script3 with exit 0 the code will go to script2.sh

How can I exit from the entire process?

Regards,

Comment: If you can find out the PIDs of your processes and they're running in parallel, you can kill them all with `kill -9`. If the scripts are run one after the other, you can exit a script with a non-zero exit code and check the last exit code before running the next script.

Comment: Sourcing a script is not the same as running a script. If you source, `exit` runs in your parent shell process. `exit` should pretty much never exist in anything you intend to source.

Comment: @user13124036 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill

Comment: You also might be better off redefining your bash _scripts_ as bash _functions_. Then any other script that would normally call another script can instead ```source``` the script (thus gaining access to the function) and then run the function. From functions you can ```return $ERRVAL```

Comment: How can I find the process of all scripts? to the script where I'm I can find it with $PPID but not for all

Comment: Also ... I'm sourcing lots of scripts are they are keeping functions ... there is an entire app developed with bash

Answer (score 1):

Replace `bash script2.sh` with `source script2.sh` and an exit in `script2.sh` is in the same process as `script1.sh`.

Check your code before choosing this solution. After changing the code the changes in the environment in `script2.sh` are also made in the environment of `script1.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

I am a personal fan of using functions. Redefine your additional bash *scripts* as bash *functions*. I refer to [this guide](http://kfirlavi.herokuapp.com/blog/2012/11/14/defensive-bash-programming/) all the time for bash style questions.

This wont work: `source Script_1.sh`
**Script_1.sh**

```
echo "Do stuff" # Some code here
source Script_2.sh
echo "Do more stuff" # Some more code here
```

**Script_2.sh**

```
echo "Do stuff" # Some code here
exit 0
```

This will work:  `source New_Script_1.sh`
**New_Script_1.sh**

```
Function_2() { 
    echo "Do stuff" # Some code here
    return 0
}

echo "Do stuff" # Some code here
Function_2
echo "Do more stuff" # Some more code here
```

The functionality of what was once *Scrpit_2.sh* now exists in *Function_2*. You don't have to `return 0` at the end, you could any number up to 8bits (0-255) if you want to. The return value from a bash function will be stored in the environment-variable `$?` and be accessible only immediately after the function call(the line after).